# What Abstract Data Type (ADT) is used to implement steinhaus-johnson-trotter (permutations) algorithm in Python?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, permutation, doubly-linked-list

What Abstract Data Type (ADT) is used to implement [steinhaus-johnson-trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) for generating permutations of objects in Python?

I am particularly worried about the complexity cost of the insertions in any location of the data:

```
1

12
21

123
132
312
```

Doubly linked list from the `llist` module is a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert new elements into the sequence, you only need to swap two elements each time. This is fast on an array. The standard Python list is implemented as an array, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, so I think it's the best data structure for this purpose.